# Automatic Custom Thumbnails for Materials in Blender's Asset Libary

Tags: python, asset-browser

Hey Blender Community,

I'm exploring ways to create custom thumbnails for materials in Blender. I'd love a straightforward method to choose a shape, apply the material, and save it as a thumbnail in the asset library. Also, figuring out how to automatically set up the lighting for this would be great. I know you can manually render and set it as a thumbnail, but I'm wondering if there's an automated process, maybe with Python? I'm not after a complete solution, just some guidance or direction. If I get a basic idea, I might seek developer assistance later.

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is a Q&A site for help with problems using Blender and its built-in addons. There are no Blender developers here, nor does anyone here have any association with the Blender Foundation. I'd suggest you try making a suggestion at https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/?sorting=hot and see if there's any interest there as your question is really off-topic for this site.